# Looking for a short film that aired on Space Channel in Canada in the late 1990s/early 2000s

Tags: story-identification, short-film

Space Channel originally had a bunch of clips that it ran along with commercials.  This one begins, I think, with the words 'we have reached the end'.  The clip is about a message (it may actually be called "Message") sent by humanity, who apparently has "reached the end" and sent out the last surviving human, a woman in stasis in a spaceship.  I believe that last line was "We do not wish to survive this way, we only want to be remembered" or something like that.

Being able to see it again on Youtube or something would be super.

Comment: This channel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CTV_Sci-Fi_Channel

Comment: Yes!  I don't own a cable TV anymore, so I didn't realize it has a new name.  It used to be "Space"